# Eclipse Installation Trouble "Installation failed with an error. Show log"

Tags: eclipse, java-11

I'm a new Java developer and trying to download and install the "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers"
But when I tried to install it it says "Installation failed with an error. Show log"
And I tried deleting and re-installing a few times and tried the same with my JDK thinking that might have something to do with it but nothing seems to change.

I've dropped the error log below where the errors started. It's a lot but hopefully someone can make more sense of it than I can. Thank you in advance!

````
[2021-04-22 08:26:20] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:291)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:551)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:343)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:899)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3851)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3779)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3760)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3638)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1156)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=C__Users_gmartinez_eclipse_jee-2021-034_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 Error reading signed content.
  java.io.IOException: Exception in opening zip file: C:\Users\gmartinez\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.ant.core_3.5.800.v20200608-1251.jar
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3851)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3779)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3760)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3638)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1156)
  Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\gmartinez\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.ant.core_3.5.800.v20200608-1251.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3851)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3779)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3760)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3638)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
    ... 1 more ```
````

Comment: Please show the log from the beginning.

Comment: You have an overeager anti-virus, or something else, opening the plug-in files when they're first downloaded, locking them from being moved to the actual folder where they're expected to end up. You'll need to temporarily disable it, or use a downloadable zip of the package from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-03/r/eclipse-ide-java-developers .